# Show that distance of disjoint sets is $0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Suppose $A = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : y = 0 \} $ and $B = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : y = \frac{1}{x} \} $. Notice that $A$ and $B$ are both closed since both are graphs of continuous functions. Furthermore, since for every $x \in \mathbb{R} $, $0 \neq \frac{1}{x} $, then we see that $A \cap B = \varnothing $. However,

$$ d(A,B) = \inf \{ || \mathbf{x} - \mathbf{y}|| : \mathbf{x} \in A, \; \; \mathbf{y} \in B \} $$

This, $d(A,B) = 0$ ??? How can I show this rigorously? thanks.

Comment: Compute the distance between $(n,0)\in A$ and $(n,1/n)\in B$.

Comment: Write as an answer to give you points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just compute the distance between $(n,0)\in A$ and $(n,1/n)\in B$ for $n\in\Bbb N$.

From this you can deduce that given $\epsilon>0$, $d(A,B)<\epsilon$. It then follows that $d(A,B)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

By the definition of the distance of the two sets $A$ and $B$ we have

$$0\le d^2(A,B)\le \left|\left|(x,0)-\left(x,\frac 1x\right)\right|\right|^2=\frac1{x^2}\longrightarrow_{x\to\infty}0 $$
so 
$$d(A,B)=0$$

Answer (score 0):

$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$: fix

Let $x_{n}=(n,0)$, $y_{n}=(n,\frac{1}{n})$ then $||x_{n}-y_{n}||=\frac{1}{n}$

Because $x_{n}\in A$, $y_{n}\in B$, $d(A,B)\leq ||x_{n}-y_{n}||=\frac{1}{n}$

Limiting $n\to \infty$, you get $d(A,B)=0$